nodejs using https to send res back to client
app.post("/weather", function(request,response) {

    let city = request.body.city;
    
    const options = {
        method: 'GET',
        hostname: 'open-weather13.p.rapidapi.com',
        port: null,
        path: "/city/" + city + "/EN",
        headers: {
            'x-rapidapi-key': '-----',
            'x-rapidapi-host': '-----'
        }
    };

    const req = http.request(options, function (res) {
        const chunks = [];

        res.on('data', function (chunk) {
            chunks.push(chunk);
        });

        res.on('end', function () {
            const body = Buffer.concat(chunks);
            console.log(body.toString());
        });

        res.send({ test: 'test' });

    });

    req.end();

});

I get the following
res.send is not a function

here is my ajax
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("form").submit(function (event) {
      
    var formData = {
      city: $("#city").val(),
    };

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "http://localhost:8002/weather",
      data: formData,
      dataType: "json",
      encode: true,
          success: function (data, status, xhr) {
    console.log('data: ', data);
  }
    }).done(function (data) {
      console.log(data);
    });

    event.preventDefault();
  });
});


res is an event of http's request, and it does not have that method, so you actually need to use express's/app's response instead:
app.post("/weather", function(request,response) {
   //...
   // now send response here
   response.send({ test: 'test' });

